# how to do positioning for mentioned below?

Tags: html, css

not able to set text on right of this image.
on inspect it is showing ornagecolor(Margin)but no margin set as such.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTRMG.png)

Comment: Also already tried, margin =0;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help us better understand what you need. Make sure to always include any relevant code using the [<>] button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex` for the parent container or you can also use `float:left` for the `img` element.

```css
.card{
  display:flex;
}
.card img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
h2,h5,p{
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546069901-ba9599a7e63c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8Zm9vZHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" width="100">
 <div>
   <h2>The big chill</h2>
   <h5>Fort</h5>
   <p>your address here ... </p>
</div>
</div>
```